# Getting the ID From MAX(SUM()) SQL GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the PlayerID from the result I get in following image

[image: Result of query]

The query I use to display that is:

```
SELECT PlayerIDFK, sum(TwoPointMade) as TwoPointMade, sum(ThreePointMade) as ThreePointMAde 
FROM PlayerPerformance GROUP BY PlayerIDFK;
```

I also have another query which returns the maximum value of sums of both columns in this case 47, which is the correct answer, but I also want to get the PlayerIDFK.

```
SELECT MAX(SUM(TwoPointMade) + SUM(ThreePointMade)) AS "Points"
FROM PlayerPerformance GROUP BY PlayerIDFK;
```

When I try to get the player ID using the query I get not a single-group group function. This is the query Im trying to use:

```
SELECT PlayerIDFK, MAX(SUM(TwoPointMade) + SUM(ThreePointMade)) AS "Points"
FROM PlayerPerformance GROUP BY PlayerIDFK;
```

Comment: Please use only the tags that match the technology you use. Is it [tag:mysql], [tag:sql-server] or [tag:oracle]?

Comment: This is not a job for `GROUP BY`. `GROUP BY` does not return rows from the table. It produces new rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order by` and `rownum` (or `fetch first 1 row only` in 12c+):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT PlayerIDFK, sum(TwoPointMade) as TwoPointMade, sum(ThreePointMade) as ThreePointMAde 
      FROM PlayerPerformance
      GROUP BY PlayerIDFK
      ORDER BY ( sum(TwoPointMade) + sum(ThreePointMade) ) desc
     ) pp
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Comment: ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply

Comment: Try removing the sum() wrappers in the ORDER BY.